# Unique ID being changed when deserializing JSON - it should stay the same

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a small class in which when the constructor is fired it generates a new unique ID. However, when I serialize it and then deserialize it my ID is being generated again because it seems to be creating a new object again. What is the easiest way to stop this behavior? (I would like to keep the unique guid generation in the constructor if possible)

```
 <Serializable>
    Public Class YubikeyPool
        Public ReadOnly Property ID As Guid
        Public Property Name As String

        Public Sub New()
            ID = Guid.NewGuid()
        End Sub
       
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return Name
        End Function
    End Class
```

Here is my Serialize/Deserialize functions

```
 Function Serialize(ByVal objData As Object) As Byte()
    If objData Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(objData, GetJsonSerializerOptions()))
End Function

Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal byteArray As Byte()) As T
    If byteArray Is Nothing OrElse Not byteArray.Any() Then Return Nothing
    Return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of T)(byteArray, GetJsonSerializerOptions())
End Function

Private Function GetJsonSerializerOptions() As JsonSerializerOptions
    Dim options = New JsonSerializerOptions
    With options
        .PropertyNamingPolicy = Nothing
        .WriteIndented = True
        .AllowTrailingCommas = True
        .DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
    End With

    Return options
End Function
```

Comment: The ID property is ReadOnly. No way for the deserializer to set it from the json data

Answer (score 3):

The constructor **WILL** run. The only way to keep a prior value is to overwrite the constructor's work and the set the value along with other properties when you deserialize... which can't happen right now because the property is marked `ReadOnly`. Start by removing that modifier.

Comment: You can also drop the explicit constructor, although one will be generated, by using default initialized [Auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties#backing-field)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a little change to your class definition, using an overloaded Constructor and decorating the default Constructor with `[JsonConstructorAttribute]`

The read-only property (here, the property has a `private` setter) can be decorated with a `[JsonIncludeAttribute]`. In this case, the non-public setter is used. For example:

(in C#, since you have tagged this language)
Assuming `System.Text.Json 7.0.0.3`

```
[Serializable]
public class YubikeyPool {
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonInclude]
    public Guid ID { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConstructor]
    public YubikeyPool() : this(string.Empty) { }

    public YubikeyPool(string name) => ID = Guid.NewGuid();

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

You can initialize a class object as you were probably doing.

```
var yp = new YubikeyPool() { Name = "Some Name" };
```

The previously auto-generated GUID is preserved when deserializing

---

I think the method used for serialization should be changed in:

```
public byte[] Serialize<T>(T objData) where T : class {
    if (objData is null) return null;
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(objData, GetJsonSerializerOptions()));
}
```

---

VB.NET version:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class YubikeyPool
    Private m_ID As Guid

    <JsonInclude>
    Public Property ID As Guid
        Get
            Return m_ID
        End Get
        Private Set()
            m_ID = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonConstructor>
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(String.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
        ID = Guid.NewGuid()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

---

```
Public Function Serialize(Of T As Class)(objData As T) As Byte()
    If objData Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(objData, GetJsonSerializerOptions()))
End Function
```